# How to apply CSS3 flex styles on descending elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just discovered CSS3's `display: flex;` property and tried to apply it to my website's sticky header, but I ran into a problem.

The goal was to evenly space **all** links across the full width of the header, but this seems impossible when semantically grouping elements with, for example, a `<nav>` tag.

See jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9bua0n7o/

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
   Logo
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="search">
    <a href="#">Search</a>
  </div>

  <div class="login">
   <a href="#">Register</a>
   <a href="#">Login</a>
  </div>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;    
    justify-content: space-between;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    padding: 0 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

Here I gave each wrapper (navigation, search, etc.) a flex value matching the amount of children they have.

That basically means that the wrapper will occupy that much of the available space and make the items evenly spread.

Then I set each link to `flex: 1` making them take its full space.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ccc;
}

header .logo,
header .search {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

header .navigation {
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
}

header .login {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
}

header .navigation a,
header .search a,
header .login a {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="search">
    <a href="#">Search</a>
  </div>

  <div class="login">
    <a href="#">Register</a>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: This worked for my case! But it leaves me wondering... Isn't there a better way to do this? What if the amount of links inside `.navigation` element changes? I would have to manually update the `flex: 3;` property to make it work again.

Comment: @Swen Since they are wrapped, their wrapper need to know how big it should be compared to the rest. If you don't wrap them and give them all `flex: 1` it will work independent of amount of links, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/804fhnj6/

Comment: @Swen For older browsers you can actually do this with `display: table-cell` as well: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/804fhnj6/1/

Comment: @Swen If you want to keep the wrappers, an alternative is to give each link a width, which again will have to be maintained when new links get added, as they can't "know" how many they are and dynamically adjust

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is similar (though not quite identical) to **LGSon**'s above.

1) I added a link to `.logo`:

```
<div class="logo">
<a href="#">Logo</a>
</div>
```

2) Then I gave *all* the elements in the header the same `flex` style:

```
.logo,
.logo a,

.navigation,
.navigation a,

.search,
.search a,

.login,
.login a {
flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

3) Finally, I overrode the `flex-grow` styles of `.navigation` and `.login`:

```
.navigation {
flex-grow: 3;
}

.login {
flex-grow: 2;
}
```

Example in full:

```css
header, .logo, .navigation, .search, .login {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo, .navigation, .search, .login, .logo a, .navigation a, .search a, .login a {
flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
flex-grow: 3;
}

.login {
flex-grow: 2;
}

header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;

position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;

padding: 0 25px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<header>

<div class="logo">
<a href="#">Logo</a>
</div>

<nav class="navigation">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">FAQ</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div class="search">
<a href="#">Search</a>
</div>

<div class="login">
<a href="#">Register</a>
<a href="#">Login</a>
</div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though (as of July 2016) certainly not a production ready solution, the [CSS Display Module Level 3 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents) defines the `display: contents` property, which dictates:

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document tree.

Applied to your solution, it might look something like this (currently only supported in Firefox):

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ccc;
}

.header-section {
  display: contents;
}

.header-section a {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>

  <nav class="header-section navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="header-section search">
    <a href="#">Search</a>
  </div>

  <div class="header-section login">
    <a href="#">Register</a>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

*Hopefully this at least provides some education on proposed new CSS features*

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. Too bad it's not widely supported yet. Very interesting!

Comment: @Swen yeh, it clearly has a great purpose in situations like this! Web development is always full of these "there's a solution, but you can't use it" outcomes!